# Reload fragment when activity finish

Tags: android

I am having fragment with list view when listitem clicks new activity starts with current list postion values after changes i went back to fragmen and how to reload fragment values.

```
public class ManageCms extends Fragment implements SearchView.OnQueryTextListener{
                int events;
                CommonSharedPref commonSharedPref;
                ListView list;
                ManageCmsAdapter manageCmsAdapter;
                List<ManageCmsModel> manageCmsModelList = new ArrayList<ManageCmsModel>();
                ArrayList<ManageCmsModel> arraylist = new ArrayList<ManageCmsModel>();
                int start=0;
                int totcheckCount;
                SearchView searchView;
                ProgressDialog pDialog;
                RequestQueue requestQueue;
                String Url="";
                public ManageCms() {

                }
                @Override
                public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

                    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_manage_cms, container,
                            false);
                    commonSharedPref =new CommonSharedPref(getActivity());
                    ((MainActivity) getActivity())
                            .setActionBarTitle("Manage CMS");
                    getCMS();
                    FabSpeedDial fabSpeedDial=(FabSpeedDial)view.findViewById(R.id.cms_fab_speed_dial);
                    list = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.list_manageCms);
                    searchView=(SearchView)view.findViewById(R.id.searchView);
                    requestQueue= Volley.newRequestQueue(getActivity());

                    // Pass results to ListViewAdapter Class
                    manageCmsAdapter = new ManageCmsAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.fragment_manage_cms_list_item,
                            manageCmsModelList);

                    // Binds the Adapter to the ListView
                    list.setAdapter(manageCmsAdapter);
                    list.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE_MODAL);
                    list.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
                    setupSearchView();
                    list.setOnTouchListener(new ListView.OnTouchListener() {
                        private long startClickTime;
                        @Override
                        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                            int action = event.getAction();
                            switch (action) {
                                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                                    // Disallow ScrollView to intercept touch events.
                                    v.getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
                                    events=1;
                                    break;

                                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                                    // Allow ScrollView to intercept touch events.
                                    v.getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(false);
                                    events=0;
                                    break;
                                /*case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                                        long clickDuration = Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis() - startClickTime;
                                        if (clickDuration >= MIN_CLICK_DURATION) {
                                            //Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "LONG PRESSED!",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                            events=1;
                                        }*//*
                                    break;*/

                            }

                            // Handle ListView touch events.
                            v.onTouchEvent(event);
                            return true;
                        }
                    });
                    list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                            int pos = adapterView.getPositionForView(view);
                            String cmsId=manageCmsModelList.get(pos).getCmsId();
                            String cmsDescription=manageCmsModelList.get(pos).getCmsDescription();
                            String cmsUrl=manageCmsModelList.get(pos).getCmsUrl();
                            String cmsTitle=manageCmsModelList.get(pos).getCmsTitle();
                            commonSharedPref.clearAll();
                            commonSharedPref.editCMS(cmsTitle,cmsUrl, cmsDescription, cmsId);
                            Intent intent=new Intent(getActivity(),EditCms.class);
                            startActivity(intent);

                        }
                    });

                    list.setMultiChoiceModeListener(new AbsListView.MultiChoiceModeListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onItemCheckedStateChanged(ActionMode mode, int position, long id, boolean checked) {

                            if(list!=null){
                                // Capture total checked items
                               int checkedCount = list.getCheckedItemCount();
                                // Set the CAB title according to total checked items
                                /*((MainActivity) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().hide();*/
                                mode.setTitle(checkedCount + " Selected");
                                manageCmsAdapter.toggleSelection(position);
                            }

                        }

                        @Override
                        public boolean onCreateActionMode(ActionMode actionMode, Menu menu) {
                            actionMode.getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_cms_management, menu);
                            return true;
                        }

                        @Override
                        public boolean onPrepareActionMode(ActionMode actionMode, Menu menu) {

                            return false;
                        }


                        @Override
                        public void onDestroyActionMode(ActionMode actionMode) {
                            manageCmsAdapter.removeSelection();
                        }
                    });
                    list.setOnScrollListener(new AbsListView.OnScrollListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView absListView, int totalItemCount) {

                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onScroll(AbsListView absListView, int firstVisibleItem, int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {
                            int test=list.getAdapter().getCount();
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                            if(test!=0 && !absListView.equals("")){
                                if (list.getLastVisiblePosition() == list.getAdapter().getCount() -1 &&
                                        list.getChildAt(list.getChildCount() - 1).getBottom() <= list.getHeight())
                                {
                                    SparseBooleanArray selected = manageCmsAdapter
                                            .getSelectedIds();
                                    if(selected.size() == 0 && test!=totcheckCount){
                                        getCMS();
                                    }

                                }
                            }
                        }
                    });
                    fabSpeedDial.setMenuListener(new SimpleMenuListenerAdapter() {
                        @Override
                        public boolean onMenuItemSelected(MenuItem menuItem) {
                            switch (menuItem.getItemId()) {
                                case R.id.action_UnBlockAll:
                                    toggleUnblockAll();
                                    return true;
                                case R.id.action_BlockAll:
                                    toggleBlockAll();
                                    return true;
                                case R.id.action_DeleteAll:
                                    toggleDeleteAll();
                                    return true;
                                case R.id.action_SelectAll:
                                    toggleSelectAll();
                                    return true;
                                case R.id.action_DeSelectAll:
                                    toggleDeSelectAll();
                                    return true;
                                default:
                                    return false;
                            }
                        }
                    });

                    return view;
                }

                private void setupSearchView() {
                    searchView.setIconifiedByDefault(false);
                    searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(this);
                    searchView.setSubmitButtonEnabled(true);
                    searchView.setQueryHint("Search Here");
                }

                private void toggleDeSelectAll() {
                    int checkcounts=manageCmsModelList.size();
                    manageCmsAdapter.removeSelection();
                    for(int i=0;i<checkcounts;i++){
                        list.setItemChecked(i, false);
                    }
                }

                private void toggleSelectAll() {

                    int checkcount=manageCmsModelList.size();
                    manageCmsAdapter.removeSelection();
                    for(int i=0;i<checkcount;i++){
                        list.setItemChecked(i, true);
                    }

                }

                private void toggleDeleteAll() {
                    SparseBooleanArray selected = manageCmsAdapter
                            .getSelectedIds();
                    if(selected.size()!=0){
                        Url=ApiConstants.MULTI_DELETE;
                        manageDelete();
                    }else{
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), R.string.select_atleat_one,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }

                }


                private void toggleBlockAll() {
                    SparseBooleanArray selected = manageCmsAdapter
                            .getSelectedIds();
                    if(selected.size()!=0){
                        Url=ApiConstants.MULTI_BLOCK;
                        manageAll();
                    }else{
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), R.string.select_atleat_one,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }

                }

                private void toggleUnblockAll() {
                    SparseBooleanArray selected = manageCmsAdapter
                            .getSelectedIds();
                    if(selected.size()!=0){
                    Url=ApiConstants.MULTI_UNBLOCK;
                    manageAll();
                    }else{
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), R.string.select_atleat_one,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }

                private void getCMS() {
                    pDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
                    pDialog.setMessage("Loading Cms...");
                    pDialog.setCancelable(false);
                    showpDialog();
                    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, ApiConstants.MANAGE_CMS+"?startLimit="+start,
                            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                                @Override
                                public void onResponse(String response) {
                                    JSONArray user = null;
                                    JSONObject jo = null;
                                    try {
                                        hidepDialog();
                                        JSONObject users = new JSONObject(response);
                                        String status = users.getString("message");
                                        totcheckCount=Integer.valueOf(users.getString("totalRecord"));
                                        if (status.equals("Success")) {
                                            user = users.getJSONArray(ProjectConstants.JSON_ARRAY);
                                            if (user.length() == 0) {
                                            } else {
                                                for (int i = 0; i < user.length(); i++) {
                                                    ManageCmsModel manageCmsModel=new ManageCmsModel();
                                                    jo = user.getJSONObject(i);
                                                    start++;
                                                    manageCmsModel.setCmsId(jo.getString("cmsId"));
                                                    manageCmsModel.setCmsDescription(jo.getString("cmsDescription"));
                                                    manageCmsModel.setCmsTitle(jo.getString("cmsTitle"));
                                                    manageCmsModel.setCmsUrl(jo.getString("cmsUrl"));
                                                    manageCmsModel.setCmsStatus(jo.getString("cmsStatus"));
                                                    manageCmsModel.setSno(String.valueOf(start));
                                                    manageCmsModelList.add(manageCmsModel);
                                                    arraylist.add(manageCmsModel);
                                                    //mAdapter.getSubscriberList().add(subscriber);
                                                }
                                                hidepDialog();
                                                manageCmsAdapter = new ManageCmsAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.fragment_feed_back_list_item,
                                                        arraylist);
                                                list.setAdapter(manageCmsAdapter);
                                                /*list.setAdapter(manageCmsAdapter);
                                                manageCmsAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();*/
                                            }

                                        } else if(status.equals("Error")){
                                            String msg=users.getString("data");
                                            Toast.makeText(getActivity(),msg,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                        }else if(status.equals("Warning")){
                                            String msg=users.getString("data");
                                            Toast.makeText(getActivity(),msg,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                        }else if(status.equals("Server error")){
                                            toggleDeSelectAll();
                                            String msg=users.getString("data");
                                            Toast.makeText(getActivity(),msg,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                        }
                                        hidepDialog();
                                    } catch (Exception e) {
                                        hidepDialog();
                                        e.printStackTrace();
                                    }
                                }
                            },
                            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                                    hidepDialog();

                                }
                            }) {
                        @Override
                        protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
                            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                            String startLimit = String.valueOf(start);
                            params.put("startLimit", startLimit);
                            return params;
                        }
                    };

                    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getActivity());
                    stringRequest.setShouldCache(false);
                    stringRequest.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(20 * 1000, 0,
                            DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));
                    requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
                }
               }

        public class EditCms extends AppCompatActivity {
            EditText edt_cmsTitle,edt_cmsUrl,edt_cmsDesc;
            String cmsId,cmsTitle,cmsUrl,cmsDescription,organizerId;
            // Progress dialog
            Button btn_editCms;
            ProgressDialog pDialog;
            RequestQueue requestQueue;
            CommonSharedPref commonSharedPref;
            private ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> userData;
            @Override
            protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                setContentView(R.layout.fragment_edit_cms);
                commonSharedPref =new CommonSharedPref(getApplicationContext());
                DataBaseHandler dataBaseHandler=new DataBaseHandler(getApplicationContext());
                userData=dataBaseHandler.getUserDetail();
                organizerId=userData.get(0).get(ProjectConstants.KEY_ORGID);

                getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Edit cms");
                getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

                edt_cmsTitle=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.edt_cmsTitle);
                edt_cmsUrl=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.edt_cmsUrl);
                edt_cmsDesc=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.edt_cmsDesc);
                SharedPreferences prefs = this.getSharedPreferences("user",
                        Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                edt_cmsTitle.setText(prefs.getString("cmsTitle", ""));
                edt_cmsUrl.setText(prefs.getString("cmsUrl",""));
                edt_cmsDesc.setText(prefs.getString("cmsDescription",""));
                cmsId=prefs.getString("cmsId","");
                btn_editCms=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_editCms);
                btn_editCms.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                        cmsTitle=edt_cmsTitle.getText().toString();
                        cmsUrl=edt_cmsUrl.getText().toString();
                        cmsDescription=edt_cmsDesc.getText().toString();
                        if(cmsTitle.equals("")){
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), R.string.cms_title,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }else if(cmsUrl.equals("")){
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), R.string.cms_url,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }else if(!Patterns.WEB_URL.matcher(cmsUrl).matches()){
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), R.string.invalid_url,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }else if(cmsDescription.equals("")){
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), R.string.cms_desc,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }else if(cmsDescription.length()<50){
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), R.string.cms_min_char,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }else{
                            editCMS();

            }

        } }

                    }
                });
            }

            public void editCMS() {
                pDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
                pDialog.setMessage("Updationg Cms...");
                pDialog.setCancelable(false);
                showpDialog();
                StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, ApiConstants.EDIT_CMS+cmsId,
                        new Response.Listener<String>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onResponse(String response) {
                                JSONArray user = null;
                                JSONObject jo=null;
                                JSONArray error = null;
                                try{
                                    hidepDialog();
                                    JSONObject users = new JSONObject(response);
                                    String status = users.getString("message");
                                    if(status.equals("Success")){
                                        String msg=users.getString("data");
                                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),msg,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                    }else if(status.equals("Error")){
                                        String msg=users.getString("data");
                                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),msg,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                    }else if(status.equals("warning")){
                                        String msg=users.getString("data");
                                        Toast.makeText(
            }

        }getApplicationContext(),msg,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                    }else if(status.equals("Server error")){
                                        String msg=users.getString("data");
                                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),msg,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                    }
                                }catch (Exception e){
                                    hidepDialog();
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        new Response.ErrorListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                                hidepDialog();
                                String errorMessage=error.getClass().getSimpleName();
                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),errorMessage,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            }
                        }){
                    @Override
                    protected Map<String,String> getParams(){
                        Map<String,String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                        params.put("cmsTitle",cmsTitle);
                        params.put("cmsUrl",cmsUrl);
                        params.put("cmsDescription",cmsDescription);
                        params.put("organizerId",organizerId);
                        return params;
                    }
                };

            }

            public void showpDialog() {
                if (!pDialog.isShowing())
                    pDialog.show();
            }

            public void hidepDialog() {
                if (pDialog.isShowing())
                    pDialog.dismiss();
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
                switch (item.getItemId()) {

                    // Respond to the action bar's Up/Home button
                    case android.R.id.home:
                        commonSharedPref.clearAll();
                        commonSharedPref.editCMS(cmsTitle,cmsUrl, cmsDescription, cmsId);
                        finish();
                        return true;
                }
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
            }
            @Override
            public void onBackPressed() {

                super.onBackPressed();

            }

        }
```

I am having fragment with list view when listitem clicks new activity starts with current list postion values after changes i went back to fragmen and how to reload fragment values.

Comment: Instead of using startActivity, user startActivityForResult and in your main activity where you putting fragment, override onActivityResult method and send a listener to fragment which will reload the list view.

Comment: where to add startActivityForResult..

Comment: On list-item clicks where the new activity starts.

Comment: thank u it wroks.....

Answer (score -1, accepted):

override onResume in your fragment and notify your adapter

```
@Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        manageCmsAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
```

when you will go to another activity onPause of the fragment will call and when coming back onResume() will call.So you can notify about data changes in the listview to the adapter